# curve fitting with both shared and independent parameters

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I have two datasets y1 and y2.I need to fit a bi-exponential curve to these two datasets with some shared and some independent parameters. T's are shared. A's are independent.

y1 = A11 exp(T1*x) + A12 exp(T2*x)

y2 = A21 exp(T1*x) + A22 exp(T2*x)

I am using numpy concatenate along with scipy.curve_fit feature to do this. I saw this example on: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348765/simultaneously-curve-fitting-for-2-models-with-shared-parameters-in-r

However when I do this, the curve looks weird. The curve always wants to touch the last data point and ruins everything. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VMyF.png)

Can anyone help me?

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

y1 = np.array([-12.852481,-30.782795,-27.368464,-41.604416,-37.335682,-67.12344,-113.15599,-102.833374])
y2 = np.array([26.30352,27.350178,30.479588,34.889896,14.752427,8.482291,-16.35122,-26.602728])
x = np.array([0.000, 0.003, 0.006, 0.015, 0.030, 0.066, 0.240, 0.700])
y = np.array([y1,y2])

def func(x, A, T1, B , T2):
    return A * np.exp(T1 * x ) + B * np.exp(T2 * x)

def combofunc(x,  A11, A12, A21, A22, T1, T2):
    return np.concatenate((func(x, A11, T1, A12, T2), func(x, A21, T1, A22, T2)))

fitted_params, pcov= curve_fit(combofunc,x,y.ravel(), maxfev=1000000)
A11, A12, A21, A22, T1, T2 = fitted_params

xx=np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 1000)
y_fit_1 = func(xx, A11, T1, A12, T2)
y_fit_2 = func(xx, A21, T1, A22, T2) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x,y1,marker='s',color='b')
ax.scatter(x,y2,marker='s',color='r')
ax.semilogx(xx, y_fit_1,ls='--',color='b')
ax.semilogx(xx, y_fit_2,ls='--',color='r')
```

Comment: it's seems to me that is not a bad adjust. Maybe it touches the last point because it's the only point after local minimun of the function. and so it's easy to adjust this only point..

Comment: If you consider it an outlier you might want to check [robust fitting](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/robust_regression.html) It is also possible that you need to put some boundaries on our parameters. Maybe such that the first derivative is always negative on your domain. Depends on what you want and what you mean by "ruins"